# Java Swing table with suboptions

Tags: java, swing

I need to create a table where each entry can be expanded and contain information about the entry. I've tried to make a sketch to illustrate what I'm aiming for.

[image: Illustration]

(Just realised the arrows on the side should be inverted.)

I'm wondering if someone could send me in the right direction of making this. Like what swing components to use etc.

Comment: It sounds like you're not looking for a Table, but a Task Pane

Comment: You can use custom `TableCellRenderer` which will return sketch of row and custom `TableCellEditor` where [`getTableCellEditorComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html#getTableCellEditorComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) will return `JPanel` with extended information and change height of row.